# SendGrid Multiple Emails to Multiple Recipients Node JS from Firebase Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using SendGrid and Firebase Functions to send multiple emails to multiple recipients. The code that I am using works correctly when sending to a test list of 4 email addresses, but does not work when trying to send to 4,000 email addresses. There is also no error message from SendGrid.

This code also works and returns the list of email addresses printed in the console if the SendGrid block of code is commented out. 
Do you know what could be going wrong?

Thank you

```
exports.adminSendGroupMessage = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const emailHTMLData = emailHTMLData;

  var emailDataArray = [];

          //Fetch contacts list
          let testContactsRef = db.collection('contacts-list');
          return testContactsRef.get().then(snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                // console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                console.log("Fetched contact with ID: " + doc.id);

                //Extract contact data
                const firstName = doc.data().name || "";
                const surname = doc.data().surname || "";
                const emailAddress = doc.data().emailAddress;

                var emailData =  {
                  to: emailAddress,
                  from: 'fromEmail@email.com',
                  subject: messageSubject,
                  text: 'Email for ' + firstName,
                  html: emailHTMLData,
                  customArgs: {
                    ref: 'msg-ref'
                  },
                }

                    //Add new email data to the array
                    emailDataArray.push(emailData);
              });

              return Promise.all(emailDataArray).then(results => {

                  //Send emails with all data once contact fetch complete
                console.log("Success fetching contacts - send emails.");
                sendGridGroupMessages(emailDataArray);
                return { success : true, message: "Success sending emails" };

            })

});

function sendGridGroupMessages(emailDataArray) {
  console.log('Send emails to group function with data: ' + emailDataArray.length);

  var i,j, splitArray,chunk = 998;
  for (i=0,j=emailDataArray.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
      splitArray = emailDataArray.slice(i,i+chunk);
      // do whatever
      //Send emails
    sgMail.send(splitArray, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        //Do something with the error
        console.log("Error sending group emails: " + error);
        // throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'There was an error sending the group emails - ' + error.message + ' (' + error.code + ')');
      } else {
        //Celebrate
        console.log("Success sending group emials: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        // return { success : true };
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must post the error log
If no errors it means they sent
but check SendGrid activities to see what happened to these emails

Comment: The activity section of SendGrid does not list these emails.

Comment: If the account new you won't see them, If you get an error from the script share it, there are a lot of opensource codes created for sendgrid only you can try them and edit them

Comment: Other emails that have been sent using a smaller, test list of contacts are listed in the Activity section. But not those send with the large list.